# Did I implement this Google Analytics Event Tracking Correctly?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

Did I implement this event tracking correctly? I want to measure clicks on a call to action at the bottom of a blog post:

```
<a href="http://marketingcuriosity.com/download-a-350-page-ebook-about-digital-analytics-for-free/" onclick=”_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘CTA’,’click’, ’red-button’])”></a>
```

For some reason It's not populating data in my reports.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly fine! I would just add a semicollon at the end and make sure you use correct apostrophe in your code

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'CTA', 'click', 'red-button']);"
```

Comment: Ah! That might be why. Thank you!!

Comment: For some reason the code isn't loading up still. Do I need to clear my cache? Here's the full url with code embedded: <a href="http://marketingcuriosity.com/download-a-350-page-ebook-about-digital-analytics-for-free/" onclick=”_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'CTA', 'click', 'red-button']);”><img src="http://marketingcuriosity.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/cta-reg.png" width="600" height="229"></a>

Comment: Dyou have ga.js loaded on your page? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#quickstart

Comment: Yes I do have the code loaded on the page. Maybe there's an initial delay in the data populating? I can't see anything in the real-time reports as well.

Comment: Try to check under Behavior>Events and see if some were recorded in there already (make sure to include todays date). It has happened to me sometimes where I wouldn't see anything realtime at first but it still were there.

Comment: Still nothing. I will wait a day or so, and let you know what I find. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just for safety, also make sure you use real colons around your onclick attr `onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'CTA', 'click', 'red-button']);"`

Comment: Does the CTA bring you to a new page? Could be that the event doesn't have enough time to fire prior to the next page loading.

Comment: No it should be fine that way..that's always how I do it on all my sites